# What is the running time and invariants of iterative merge sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I wanted to know that if there is a difference between running times and invariants of iterative and recursive merge sort. How to change the Merge sort (iterative or recursive version) in such a way that the best case is the same as in the case of Insertion sort?

Comment: please show some of the work you have already done to get an understanding yourself and where specifically did you face an issue in understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there was *Pseudo code* it would be much more sense able. *However*, There is not any difference in running times of iterative or recursive implementation and the only difference is that, the recursive implementation is much more readable and convenient compared to iterative one. both implementations have `O(nLogn)` running time.

> How to change the Merge sort (iterative or recursive version) in such
> a way that the best case is the same as in the case of Insertion sort

Merge sort is neutral to input that means, either sorted or not sorted input will have `O(nLogn)` so THERE IS NOT BEST CASE OR WORSE CASE AND ALWAYS `O(nLogn)`.
*On the other hand*, insertion sort is not neutral to input that means, in best case it has `O(n)` running time when the input is sorted and in worse case is `O(n^2)` when input is reverse sorted.

> I wanted to know that if there is a difference between running times
> and invariants of iterative and recursive merge sort.
>
> In computer science, a loop invariant is a property of a program loop
> that is true before each iteration. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant)

[iterative](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-merge-sort/) implementation invariant

```
curr_size<=n-1

left_start<n-1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering you can check java code for them here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-merge-sort/ if that works and can you also tell me about invariants of the main loop?

Comment: You did not answer this part: *How to change the Merge sort (iterative or recursive version) in such a way that the best case is the same as in the case of Insertion sort?*

Comment: @chqrlie i did and the answer is in capital case words.

Comment: Not really. You just state that mergesort has a uniform time complexity of **N.log(N)** which no one contests, the OP wants to know if mergesort can be **modified** to improve the complexity for the best case of insertion sort, which is linear for sorted lists. The answer is yes as exposed in my answer. This is no longer pure merge sort, but a lightly modified merge sort.

Comment: @chqrlie then it's not Merge Sort , it's extended Merge sort or new implementation of the original one. as matter of fact when dealing with algorithms we must inspect it within it's implementation and adding or removing to/from it is out of it's main implementation.

Comment: @chqrlie for example Quick-Sort can have several implementation in it's main implementation in how we partition the input list , Random partition , Selection Partition and so on, but they are not violating original implementation and all of them are quick-sort as because the partitioning is free to any new implementation .

Comment: @chqrlie so i can confidentially say that there is a worse case `O(nLogn)` in quick-sort even though some other implementations may have `O(n^2)` without violating originality. but this is not hold for Merge-Sort.

Comment: @Mr.AF: we agree that it would be a *modified merge sort*, but that seems to be one of the OP's questions.

Comment: @chqrlie if the OP purpose was modifying merge sort that's right. btw, i fully respect you

Comment: @Mr.AF: so do I :)

Answer (score 1):

Iterative and recursive merge sort variants, also referred to as top-down and bottom-up merge sort have the same time complexity **O(N.log(N))** and stability. The running time may be affected by quality of implementation, especially cache friendliness, efficiency of the working space allocation method and effective balancing of the fragment sizes for bottom-up merging, which is automatic in top-down merge sort. An interesting and sometimes useful property is the time complexity does not depend on the actual data distribution. There is no *best case* and *worst case* in classic implementations, just a constant time complexity of **O(N.log(N))**.

You can modify the merge sort algorithm to exhibit a better time complexity on arrays that are mostly sorted as ascending or descending order at a small cost, while keeping the same average and worst case time complexity of **O(N.log(N))**:

Adding an extra test at the beginning of the merge phase to verify if the halves are already ordered just adds `N` tests but reduces the complexity to linear **O(N)** for sorted arrays.

Another common optimisation for both top-down and bottom-up merge sort is falling back to insertion sort for chunks smaller than a given threshold. This does not change the average time complexity but does improve the running times by a noticeable factor on sorted or almost sorted arrays.

Answer (score 0):

To change merge sort to get a best case time of O(n), a scan needs to be done to see if the data is already sorted. There are variations of merge sort that scan data to find existing sorted runs, such as Timsort, but that is a hybrid of merge sort and insertion sort.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

If the sort does not need to be stable (preserve the order of equal elements), then any inversion (data[i+1] < data[i]) can be treated as a sorted run boundary. If the sort needs to be stable, then some method will be needed to keep track of run boundaries (such as an array of indexes or pointers).

A pure merge sort has time complexity O(n log(n)), and the number of moves is always the same, but if the data is already sorted, then the number of compares is cut in about half.